# Is the order of the equality operator important in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operators, bcrypt, equality, commutativity

I have used the bcrypt library in my Ruby program. I noticed that the order of the equality operator seems to be important. Depending on which variable is left or right of the '==' I get a different result.
Here is an example program:

```
require 'bcrypt'
my_pw = "pw1"
puts "This is my unhashed password: #{my_pw}"
hashed_pw = BCrypt::Password.create(my_pw)
puts "This is my hashed password: #{hashed_pw}"

20.times{print"-"}
puts

puts "my_pw == hashed_pw equals:"
if (my_pw == hashed_pw)
  puts "TRUE"
else
  puts "FALSE"
end

puts "hashed_pw == my_pw equals:"
if (hashed_pw == my_pw)
  puts "TRUE"
else
  puts "FALSE"
end
```

Regards
schande

Comment: `==` just like most Ruby operators resolves to a _method call_, so the behavior is up to its _receiver_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

`my_pw == hashed_pw` calls the `==` method on the `my_pw` string and passes `hashed_pw` as an argument. That means you are using the `String#==` method. From the [docs of `String#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D):

> ```
> string == object → true or false
> ```
>
> Returns `true` if `object` has the same length and content; as `self`; `false` otherwise

Whereas `hashed_pw == my_pw` calls the `==` method on an instance of `BCrypt::Password` and passes `my_pw` as an argument. From the docs of [`BCrypt::Password#==`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/BCrypt%2FPassword:==):

> ```
> #==(secret) ⇒ Object
> ```
>
> Compares a potential secret against the hash. Returns `true` if the secret is the original secret, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with equality. This is just fundamentals of Object-Oriented Programming.

In OOP, all computation is done by objects sending messages to other objects. And one of the *fundamental properties* of OOP is that the receiver object *and only the receiver object* decides how to respond to this message. This is how encapsulation, data hiding, and abstraction are achieved in OOP.

So, if you send the message `m` to object `a` passing `b` as the argument, then `a` gets to decide how to interpret this message. If you send the message `m` to object `b` passing `a` as the argument, then it is `b` which gets to decide how to interpret this message. There is no built-in mechanism that would guarantee that `a` and `b` interpret this message the same. *Only* if the two objects decide to coordinate with each other, will the response actually be the same.

If you think about, it would be very weird if `2 - 3` and `3 - 2` had the same result.

That is exactly what is happening here: In the first example, you are sending the message `==` to `my_pw`, passing `hashed_pw` as the argument. `my_pw` is an instance of the [`String` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html), thus the `==` message will be dispatched to the [`String#==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-3D) method. This method knows how to compare the receiver object to another `String`. It does, however, not know how to compare the receiver to a [`BCrypt::Password`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/bcrypt/BCrypt/Password), which is what the class of `hashed_pw` is.

And if you think about it, that makes sense: `BCrypt::Password` is a third-party class from outside of Ruby, how *could* a built-in Ruby class know about something that didn't even *exist* at the time the `String` class was implemented?

In your second example, on the other hand, you are sending the message `==` to `hashed_pw`, passing `my_pw` as the argument. This message gets dispatched to the [`BCrypt::Password#==`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/bcrypt/BCrypt/Password:==) method, which *does* know how to compare the receiver with a `String`:

> ## Method: `BCrypt::Password#==`
>
> **Defined in**: lib/bcrypt/password.rb
>
> `#==(secret)` ⇒ `Object`
> Also known as: `is_password?`
>
> Compares a potential secret against the hash. Returns `true` if the secret is the original secret, `false` otherwise.

Actually, the problem in this particular case is even more subtle than it may at first appear.

I wrote above that `String#==` doesn't know what to do with a `BCrypt::Password` as an argument, because it only knows how to compare `String`s. Well, actually `BCrypt::Password` inherits from `String`, meaning that a `BCrypt::Password` **IS-A** `String`, so `String#==` *should* know how to handle it!

But think about what `String#==` does:

> ## `string == object` → `true` or `false`
>
> Returns `true` if `object` has the same length and content; as `self`; `false` otherwise […]

Think about this: "returns `true` if `object` has the same length and content". For a hash, this will practically never be true. `self` will be something like `'P@$$w0rd!'` and `object` will be something like `'$2y$12$bxWYpd83lWyIr.dF62eO7.gp4ldf2hMxDofXPwdDZsnc2bCE7hN9q'`, so clearly, they are neither the same length nor the same content. And `object` *cannot possibly be* the same content because the whole point of a cryptographically secure password hash is that you *cannot* reverse it. So, even if `object` somehow wanted to present itself as the original password, it couldn't do it.

The only way this would work, is if `String` and `BCrypt::Password` could somehow "work together" to figure out equality.

Now, if we look close at the documentation of `String#==`, there is actually a way to make this work:

> If `object` is not an instance of String but responds to `to_str`, then the two strings are compared using `object.==`.

So, if the author of `BCrypt::Password` had made a different design decision, then it would work:

1. Do not let `BCrypt::Password` inherit from `String`.
2. Implement `BCrypt::Password#to_str`. This will actually allow `BCrypt::Password` to be used practically interchangeably with `String` because any method that accepts `String`s should *also* accept objects that respond to `to_str`.

Now, as per the documentation of `String#==`, if you write `my_pw == hashed_pw`, the following happens:

1. `String#==` notices that `hashed_pw` is not a `String`.
2. `String#==` notices that `hashed_pw` *does* respond to `to_str`.
3. Therefore, it will send the message `object == self` (which in our case is equivalent to `hashed_pw == my_pw`), which means we are now in the second scenario from your question, which works just fine.

Here's an example of how that would work:

```ruby
class Pwd
  def initialize(s)
    @s = s.downcase.freeze
  end

  def to_str
    p __callee__
    @s.dup.freeze
  end

  def ==(other)
    p __callee__, other
    @s == other.downcase
  end

end

p = Pwd.new('HELLO')
s = 'hello'

p == s
# :==
# "hello"
#=> true

s == p
# :==
# "hello"
#=> true
```

As you can see, we are getting the results we are expecting, and `Pwd#==` gets called both times. Also, `to_str` never gets called, it only gets inspected by `String#==`.

So, it turns out that ironically, the problem is not so much that `String#==` doesn't know how to deal with `BCrypt::Password` objects, but actually the problem is that it *does* know how to deal with them *as generic `String`s*. If they weren't `String`s but merely responded to `to_str`, then `String#==` would actually know to ask them for help.

[`Numeric`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html) objects in Ruby have a whole [coercion protocol](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Numeric.html#method-i-coerce) to make sure arithmetic operations between different "number-like" operand types are supported even for third-party numerics libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions would be equivalent if both operands were, for instance, of type String.  In your case, one operand is a `String` and the other one is a `BCrypt::Password`.  Therefore `my_pw == hashed_pw` invokes the equality method defined in the String class, while `hashed_pw == my_pw` invokes the one defined in BCrypt::Password.

I have never worked with BCrypt::Password, but would expect that you get `false` for the former and `true` for the latter.

Comment: "The expressions would be equivalent if both operands were, for instance, of type String" – If you look closely, the problem is more subtle. `hashed_pw` *is*, in fact, an instance of `String` because `BCrypt::Password` inherits from `String`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : You are right. Nomenclature is tricky here. With "x is of type Y", I meant here `x.class == Y` and not `x.is_a?(Y)`. This was sloppy speech of my side: I should have said that the classes are not identical. The main argument is still valid, i.e. that the password class defines its own equality operator, which is the reason why equality here is not commutative.

Comment: @JärgWMittag : Actually, the fact that the Password class is derived from String (as it is shown [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/BCrypt/Password) surprises me. I wonder what methods from `String` can reasonably be used for a `Password` object? I (hopefully) can not search a Password string for substrings.

Comment: @user1934428 You can, though `Password` content is the hash, not the original password, so the result of this search might not be what a would-be blackhat might expect. For example, given `p = BCrypt::Password.create("my pretty password")`, then `p.include?("$12$")` is `true`, but `p.include?("pretty")` is `false`. The only new methods are `::create` and `#==`.

Comment: @Amadan : I was aware of this possibility. That#s why I said _what methods can **reasonably** be used_. Honestly, a cleaner design of the Password class would be IMHO to not inherit from String, but provide a method for extracting the encrypted password (so that it can be stored in a database for instance).

Comment: I was mainly responding to "I (hopefully) can not search a Password string for substrings". But a bcrypt hash _is_ a string (though the name of the class might be a bit misleading), whether or not the string methods can be used reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can override the equality method for a given class or instance:

```
class Test
  define_method(:==) do |_other|
    true
  end
end

Test.new == 'foo' # => true
Test.new == nil # => true
Test.new == 42 # => true

'foo' == Test.new # => false
nil == Test.new # => false
42 == Test.new # => true
```

Generally speaking, it's considered bad practice to override equality without making it symetric, but you sometimes see it in the wild.

Comment: You can define it via `def ==(other)`